# php regular expressions groups

Tags: php, regex

I am new to php and regex, and I am facing a problem.

I have a text looks like this for example: "FIRST NAME: sdfksdfkjskdlfjlskdf MORE DATA: dsfkskldfjsdkfjsdkf EXTRA DATA: dsfksdfjlsdjfklsdf"

and I want to fecth three groups, one for FIRST NAME another for MORE DATA and a third one for EXTRA DATA. so this is my regex:

`FIRST NAME:(.*)MORE DATA:(.*)EXTRA DATA:(.*)`

this is how I do it in java.

but now, how do I match it with php so I can echo something like:

`echo "more data: " . matche(group(1));`

for example.

thank you!

EDIT: and what if I have it repeating it self? for example: `FIRST NAME: sdfksdfkjskdlfjlskdf MORE DATA: dsfkskldfjsdkfjsdkf EXTRA DATA: dsfksdfjlsdjfklsdf FIRST NAME: sdfksdfkjskdlfjlskdf MORE DATA: dsfkskldfjsdkfjsdkf EXTRA DATA: dsfksdfjlsdjfklsdf` how do I grap the groups in a while loop until it ends matching?

Comment: Will the structure always be random, alphanumeric characters after the `:` in each segment? If so, you could just use `explode` and split at that delimiter which would return an array. If you need better control over this, you can use `preg_split`

Comment: something like **[this](http://ideone.com/xJOd46)**

Comment: @rock321987 thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Let's do it like this:

```
preg_match('/FIRST NAME:\s*(.*?)\s*MORE DATA:\s*(.*?)\s*EXTRA DATA:\s*(.*)\s*/', $line, $matches);
```

Your match results will now be in `$matches`, like this:

```
php > var_dump($matches);
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(93) "FIRST NAME: sdfksdfkjskdlfjlskdf MORE DATA: dsfkskldfjsdkfjsdkf EXTRA DATA: dsfksdfjlsdjfklsd"
  [1]=>
  string(20) "sdfksdfkjskdlfjlskdf"
  [2]=>
  string(19) "dsfkskldfjsdkfjsdkf"
  [3]=>
  string(17) "dsfksdfjlsdjfklsd"
}
php >
```

So now `$matches[1]` is the first group, and so on. `[0]` is the whole match result.

Answer (score 1):

Based strictly on your input:

```
$re = "/(FIRST NAME\\s*:)\\s*(.*)(MORE DATA\\s*:\\s*)(.*)(EXTRA DATA\\s*:\\s*)(.*)/"; 
$str = "FIRST NAME: sdfksdfkjskdlfjlskdf MORE DATA: dsfkskldfjsdkfjsdkf EXTRA DATA: dsfksdfjlsdjfklsdf"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Then check `$matches` variable. This way you will have groups with matches: `FIRST NAME:first-name-value`, `MORE DATA: more-data-value`, `EXTRA DATA: extra-data-value`.

Comment: and what if I have it repeating it self? for example: `FIRST NAME: sdfksdfkjskdlfjlskdf MORE DATA: dsfkskldfjsdkfjsdkf EXTRA DATA: dsfksdfjlsdjfklsdf FIRST NAME: sdfksdfkjskdlfjlskdf MORE DATA: dsfkskldfjsdkfjsdkf EXTRA DATA: dsfksdfjlsdjfklsdf` how do I grap the groups in a while loop until it ends matching?

Comment: @danijinji for repeating (capturing everything in a group) simply surround pattern within braces: https://regex101.com/r/uK8hU5/1

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is designed to only find one match per no-newline string in any regex engine because the last `.*` matches any chars, 0 or more times.

If your input always has these 3 parts repeated any number of times, use lazy dot matching and add a positive lookahead after the last one to make sure we match up to the end of string or the `FIRST NAME:`:

```
FIRST NAME:(.*?)MORE DATA:(.*?)EXTRA DATA:(.*?)(?=$|FIRST NAME:)
           ^^^^^          ^^^^^           ^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gR5uN3/1)

Here, `(.*?)` matches 0+ any chars other than a newline as few times as possible, and `(?=$|FIRST NAME:)` zero-width assertion requires `.*?` matching up to what comes first: either end of string or `FIRST NAME:`.

PHP note: in Java, you use a `Matcher#find` to find partial matches and run a `while` loop. In PHP, you just [use `preg_match_all`](http://ideone.com/ofokU3):

```
$re = "/FIRST NAME:(.*?)MORE DATA:(.*?)EXTRA DATA:(.*?)(?=$|FIRST NAME:)/"; 
$str = "FIRST NAME: sdfksdfkjskdlfjlskdf MORE DATA: dsfkskldfjsdkfjsdkf EXTRA DATA: dsfksdfjlsdjfklsdf FIRST NAME: sdfksdfkjskdlfjlskdf MORE DATA: dsfkskldfjsdkfjsdkf EXTRA DATA: dsfksdfjlsdjfklsdf"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]); // Print Group 1
print_r($matches[2]); // Print Group 2
print_r($matches[3]); // Print Group 3
```

And if you are a regex optimization fan, unroll the lazy matching groups:

```
FIRST NAME:([^M]*(?:M(?!ORE DATA:)[^M]*)*)MORE DATA:([^E]*(?:E(?!XTRA DATA:)[^E]*)*)EXTRA DATA:([^F]*(?:F(?!IRST NAME:)[^F]*)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gR5uN3/2)